# create AD-User in c#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am trying to create a new AD-User with this code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain", "ou=some_ou, dc=Mydomain");
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, account, passwd, true);
user.GivenName = Givenname;
user.Surname = Surname;
user.DisplayName = Displayname;
user.UserPrincipalName = account + "@Domain";                
user.Save();
```

The User is created without error. But I also have to set properties like Address etc, so the code continues with:

```
string distname = user.DistinguishedName;
DirectoryEntry duser = new DirectoryEntry(distname);
try
{
    duser.Properties["company"].Value = "Company";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Now I am getting

> Error: System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode -532459699

The string `distname` shows the correct distinguished name.

Comment: Could you please try [this](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/complusexceptions-in-net/)? It should give you another view of the exception that is being thrown. It might be more informative than just the code.

Comment: At what line does the exception happen, and is this new Directory Entry code happen before or after you call `user.Save()`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what is causing your problem but one thing that may make things easier on you and may clear up some errors due to you improperly using both `DirectoryServices` and `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` at the same time is [creating a new class that includes the company attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118122/How-to-use-AD-Attributes-not-represented-in-UserPr).

Its actually not that hard to do.

```
[DirectoryObjectClass("user")]
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context) { }

    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context, string samAccountName, string password, bool enabled)
        : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {
    }

    [DirectoryProperty("company")]
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("company").Length != 1)
                return null;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("company")[0];

        }
        set { this.ExtensionSet("company", value); }
    }
}
```

You can then just modify your code to

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain", "ou=some_ou, dc=Mydomain");
UserPrincipalEx user = new UserPrincipalEx(ctx, account, passwd, true);
user.GivenName = Givenname;
user.Surname = Surname;
user.DisplayName = Displayname;
user.UserPrincipalName = account + "@Domain"; 
user.Company = "Company";
user.Save();
```

My hunch is you are having some kind of interaction with the two methods of interfacing with active directory, if you switch to a single interface your problem may just go away.

Answer (score 0):

For DirectoryEntry, you have to specify the protocol (LDAP, GC, WinNT, ...).  So you would have to do:

```
DirectoryEntry duser = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + distname);
```

Note that the protocol is case sensitive, LDAP has to be all caps.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using credentials in the UserPrincipal,

Did you forgot to use them when creating your DirectoryEntry?
Also, you need to add "LDAP://" before you server name

Try something like :

```
DirectoryEntry duser = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + distname);
duser.Username = account;
duser.Password = passwd;
duser.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
```