# Can I mix DirectoryServices with AccountManagement?

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices, account-management

I'm writing some code that involves Active Directory.  Is it generally acceptable to mix calls to `System.DirectoryServices` with calls to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`?  Are the two libraries designed to be used interchangeably or should I choose one and stick to that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something specific I need that `AccountManagement` doesn't do [by creating new inherited classes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118122/How-to-use-AD-Attributes-not-represented-in-UserPr) I will try to stick to just using `AccountManagment` with the extra classes, [I have seen issues where you try to use both at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447423/create-ad-user-in-c-sharp).

Comment: One possible problem with AccountManagement is that it seems very slow when iterating through a large number of search results.  It may not be feasible to use it all of the time??

Comment: @PaulMatthews I ran in to a similar issue in the past. Depending on how you are iterating it may be making separate queries to the server.

Comment: Yes that does seem to be the case.  Do you know if this behaviour can be modified?  How did you solve the problem?

Comment: The way I solved it was by making a class that held the information I needed and copied the information I needed in to it. It is very easy to do using [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). It will let you turn an array of `UserPrincipals` in to an array of `MyUserPrincipalDTO` or whatever you call your class with a simple call of `var collectionOfDtos = Mapper.Map<MyUserPrincipalDTO>(collectionOfUserPrincipals);`. By doing it this way all the info is queried from the server all at once and accessing each element is much faster.

Comment: Ok I had a look at Automapper and it looks interesting but I'm not exactly sure how that would cause all queries to be run at once??  Does Automapper spin off a separate thread or something like that?  Not sure how it all works under the hood?